# Routing geographical data with neo4j

Tags: routes, neo4j

I have a road network in PostGIS, on which I have performed several treatments. Each road now has a custom cost, not only based on its length. These are only polylines, I currently have no layer with the netwotk nodes. I would like to compute shortest paths on this network using **neo4j**. I imagine 2 ways to do it :

- Using neo4j-spatial, I could import a shapefile taken from my PostGIS database. However, I have no control on the import process. I just tried it and I fail to find the nodes for example, because I don't know their ids (nodes created by the shapefile importer)
- Whithout using neo4j-spatial, I could write a custom converter to create the network nodes, their relationships, and import it in neo4j. However, I think this way would make me loose the ability to run geographical queries in neo4j (e.g. the user chooses to start from a XY point, find the closest network node)

Do you have advices ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Neo4j-Spatial, you can create a EditableLayer and add lines to it, thus using the spatial operations available, see e.g. https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/LayersTest.java#L121 for an example with a Polygon, and a search on it.